# Cannot install libc6: Depends: libgcc-s1 but it is not installable

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

I got my rPi in a major mess, after setting a newer apt source and upgrading. I can no longer install libc6, e.g.

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` contents:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

And apt warns me about upgradable packages, which turns out, I cannot upgrade.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
16 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libc-bin/stable 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1]
libc-dev-bin/stable 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1]
libc6-dev/stable 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1]
libc6/stable 2.31-13+rpt2+rpi1+deb11u2 armhf [upgradable from: 2.28-10+rpt2+rpi1]
libpam-chksshpwd/stable 1.4.0-9+deb11u1+rpt1 armhf [upgradable from: 1.3.1-5+rpt2]
libpam-modules-bin/stable 1.4.0-9+deb11u1+rpt1 armhf [upgradable from: 1.3.1-5+rpt2]
libpam-modules/stable 1.4.0-9+deb11u1+rpt1 armhf [upgradable from: 1.3.1-5+rpt2]
librtimulib-dev/stable 7.2.1-6 armhf [upgradable from: 7.2.1-5]
librtimulib-utils/stable 7.2.1-6 armhf [upgradable from: 7.2.1-5]
librtimulib7/stable 7.2.1-6 armhf [upgradable from: 7.2.1-5]
nodered/stable 2.1.6-2 armhf [upgradable from: 1.3.4-1]
python-sense-emu-doc/stable 1.2-1 all [upgradable from: 1.1.2]
python3-rtimulib/stable 7.2.1-6 armhf [upgradable from: 7.2.1-5]
python3-spidev/stable 20200602~200721-1 armhf [upgradable from: 20200602~200721-1~buster]
thonny/stable 3.3.14-1+rpt1 all [upgradable from: 3.3.10-1+rpt1]
xcompmgr/stable 1.1.8-1+rpt1 armhf [upgradable from: 1.1.7-1+rpt1]
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libgcc-s1 but it is not installable
         Depends: libcrypt1 but it is not installable
         Recommends: libnss-nis but it is not installable
         Recommends: libnss-nisplus but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

It all started after I jumped from stretch to newer releases.

How can I resolve this, and fix broken packages?

NOTE: `/etc/os-release` still says buster.

NOTE: kernel is `5.15.32-v7l+`

NOTE: Hardware  is Pi4 Model B with 4GByte RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got passed this issue by replacing the source.

I now use:

```
deb [trusted=yes] http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/raspbian/raspbian bullseye main
```